# Getting a hyperlink URL from an Excel document

Tags: python, xlrd

I am reading [an Excel file](http://phihag.de/2011/so/so-xls-hyperlink/IEsummary.xls) using [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd). In one column I have a company name which is formatted as a hyperlink (meaning there is a URL behind it). When I get the cell value I only get the company name. How can I also get the URL behind it?

Below is the code for reading an Excel file using the xlrd module (assume files are imported).

```
mainData_book = xlrd.open_workbook("IEsummary.xls", formatting_info=True)
mainData_sheet = mainData_book.sheet_by_index(0) # Get the first sheet 0
start = 1
end = 101
for counter in range(start, end):
    rowValues = mainData_sheet.row_values(counter, start_colx=0, end_colx=8)
    company_name = rowValues[0] #how i can get link here also??
```

Comment: please post some code so we can have a foundation to answer from!   And try to fix the title to include relevant keywords.

Comment: @Aamir Adnan Added a link to an example file. Did I capture the structure correctly? Feel free to replace it with a link to an example file of yours.

Comment: @phihag: thanks, this now makes more sense to question:) (i dont know why i got negative vote on this question this is genuine question guys, please help generously)

Comment: @Aamir Adnan I'd wager the downvotes stem from the original unspecific question title and the lack of reproducability. Also, try to observe proper punctuation. The occasional mistaek is ignored, but it can be hard to read text without commas and full stops.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In xlrd 0.7.2 or newer, you can use [`hyperlink_map`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet.hyperlink_map-attribute):

```
import xlrd
mainData_book = xlrd.open_workbook("IEsummary.xls", formatting_info=True)
mainData_sheet = mainData_book.sheet_by_index(0)
for row in range(1, 101):
    rowValues = mainData_sheet.row_values(row, start_colx=0, end_colx=8)
    company_name = rowValues[0]

    link = mainData_sheet.hyperlink_map.get((row, 0))
    url = '(No URL)' if link is None else link.url_or_path
    print(company_name.ljust(20) + ': ' + url)
```

Comment: from where i can download the xlrd 0.7.2 version?

Comment: @Adamari Adnan I checked out the development version with `svn co https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/`. Looks like 0.7.2 isn't released yet.

Comment: note that this doesn't work with `.xlsx` files yet (version 1.1.0), [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13914953/2098939)