# python xlutils : formatting_info=True not yet implemented

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I've got simple code to copy files with xlutils, xlrd, xlwt (downloaded new libraries from python-excel.org) with not loosing formatting. I've got an error as below:

```
from xlwt.Workbook import *
from xlwt.Style import *
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlrd

style = XFStyle()
rb = open_workbook('file_master.xlsx', formatting_info=True)
wb = copy(rb.get_sheet(0))

new_book = Workbook()
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
w_sheet.write(6,6)

wb.save('new_file_master.xls')
```

Error:

```
 raise NotImplementedError("formatting_info=True not yet implemented")
NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented
```

Could you please help me how to work around this or rather make it work?

Answer (score 38):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-excel/w2AoQkX3TZc/1qjT1KzwoUsJ) the flag

```
formatting_info=True
```

is only working for xls-files, but not for xlsx yet (Version xlrd-0.8.0).

As a workaround you could convert the workbook to xls using Excel or OpenOffice.

It seems that a commandline conversion from xlsx to xls is possible using [Unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) on Linux, Windows and MacOSX.