# How to copy correctly ".xlsx" file with Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, openpyxl

I am working with Excel and Python.
I want to copy and modify an Excel file with ".xlsx" extension, using a script written in Python.
The file contains a specific format and some cells have a specific styles.
When I am working with ".xls" extension file, I am using "formatting_info" for copying the Excel file in a workbook like this:

```
readBook = open_workbook(fileName, formatting_info=True)
```

and then modified it and then save it.

The problem is that I can't use "formatting_info" with ".xlsx" file;

I got an error:

```
formatting_info=True not yet implemented
```

I was looking for a solution; but I didn't find anything which helped me.

The question is: is there a way to copy and modify that ".xlsx" file and keep the style and the font?

I attach an example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have already tried using openpyxl.

Comment: There is another library called [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/), have you tried that one?

Comment: No. I will try it. It looks promising. Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried XlsxWriter, but unfortunately it has a big disadvantaged: "It cannot read or modify existing Excel XLSX files." :(

Comment: @RemusAvram only openpyxl supports both *reading* and *writing* files. Please file any issues on the bug tracker and use the mailing list for general questions.

Comment: @bernie: Your information is out of date. `xlrd` *does* read `.xlsx` files. What it doesn't do is read the *formatting* in `.xlsx` files. (It *does* read the formatting in `.xls` files, however, which is why OP framed his question the way he did.)

Comment: @user2385133 thank you for your advise. I will try to do that. I think they have already answered at this question for many times.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnY. I deleted my other comment.

Answer (score 2):

The same is the case, there is at the following link:

[python xlutils : formatting_info=True not yet implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892307/python-xlutils-formatting-info-true-not-yet-implemented)

```
formatting_info=True
```

only works on .xls not .xlsx file.