# pandas read excel as formatted

Tags: python, excel, pandas

how do i get the values of a spreadsheet as they are formatted? im working on spreadsheets with a currency format

this for example:

```
ITEM NAME UNIT PRICE
item1     USD 99
item2     SGD 45
```

but the terms 'USD' and 'SGD' were added using the formatting capabilities of excel, and is not seen by the read_excel function of pandas. i would get the values, but not the currency name. i could only work on the spreadsheets as it is, and given that i have various spreadsheets with about 6-7 sheets each, i was hoping to have a pandas (or python)-level solution rather than an excel-level solution.

thanks guys.

to Daniel, this is how i implemented the 'xlrd' engine, which didn't seem to do anything.

```
excel = pd.ExcelFile('itemlist.xlsx', sheetname=None)
master = pd.DataFrame(None)

for sheet in excel.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(excel,sheet,header=2, engine='xlrd')
    master=master.append(df)
```

Comment: pandas uses internally `xlrd` which can parse formatting information, too.

Comment: @Daniel edited my post to show how i implemented the xlrd engine, although i seem to be misssing something

Answer (score 12):

There's not any great way to do this.  `pandas` has no knowledge of the number formats, and `xlrd` doesn't seem to be able to read formats from a .xlsx file - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892307/python-xlutils-formatting-info-true-not-yet-implemented)

You could use `openpyxl` to accomplish this, it at least has access to the number formats, but it looks like you'd have to basically implement all the parsing logic yourself.

```
In [26]: from openpyxl import load_workbook

In [27]: wb = load_workbook('temp.xlsx')

In [28]: ws = wb.worksheets[0]

In [29]: ws.cell("B2")  # numeric value = 4, formatted as "USD 4"
Out[29]: <Cell Sheet1.B2>

In [30]: ws.cell("B2").value
Out[30]: 4

In [31]: ws.cell("B2").number_format
Out[31]: '"USD "#'
```

Answer (score 1):

to anyone having the same problem, i did it by separating each sheet into CSVs, using this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/561923/how-can-one-split-an-excel-xlsx-file-that-contains-multiple-sheets-into-sep)

It preserves the currency details as displayed in the spreadsheet, and while a little cumbersome, it did the job anyway.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot! I ended up using `unoconv` on the command line to batch convert all the excel files ( over 1k! ) into CSV files before processing them with `python`.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly speaking, `xlrd` allows you to access cell format info.

```py
book = xlrd.open_workbook("tmp/test.xls", formatting_info=True)  
xf_index = book.sheet_by_index(0).cell_xf_index(5,7)  
xf = book.xf_list[xf_index]  
fmt = book.format_map[xf.format_key]  
print(fmt.format_str, fmt.type)
```

Comment: This works for '.xls' file formats only, and not for '.xlsx' file formats

Comment: @Malgo you are right. There is no library that works with both formats. You need to implement it separately for every format. I just showed how it could be implemented for the '.xls' format.