# Extract format and data from xlsx sheet pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx, xls

I have some problems to extract the format and data of the template sheet. At the moment with my code I can extract only the data values.

```
import pandas as pd

template = pd.read_excel('Template_sugerencia.xlsx', sheet_name='template')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Completo.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
template.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Recomendaciones', startcol=5, startrow=Recom_len, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas read excel as formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038428/pandas-read-excel-as-formatted)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to extract the format using `pandas`.
But what you could do instead is format your sheet once the data has been extracted .
See below:

```
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Recomendaciones']

format_xl = workbook.add_format({
    'font_name': 'Arial',
    'font_size' : 12,
    'font_color': 'red',
    })

#           Args => (<range>, <col width>, <css>)
worksheet.set_column('A:ZZ', None, format_xl)
```