# pandas - read excel values as it appears in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to read excel values as they appear in excel. I understand python extracts the intrinsic values from excel not the formatted version but I'm interested in the formatted version.

Is there any way to do this in pandas?

I know I can do it in other libraries like openpyxl but I'm interested to find out if pandas can somehow do this?

Here's a sample of the excel data

[image]

Here's what the data looks like when using pandas

[image]

Note - the formatting is not fixed, so I cannot simply convert each row/cell myself.

Similar to this question but it was asked almost 3 years ago. [pandas read excel as formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038428/pandas-read-excel-as-formatted)

Comment: Can you show us the expected output ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data after putting it in pandas? You have multiple data types in the same column so the only way you could represent it (even if you could do it) is as a string, which kind of limits what you're able to do with it

Comment: The data will be piped into another programme which does fun things. I'd be happy if all the values were strings. I tried it but failed.

Comment: `df = df.astype(str)`?

Comment: I think you would have to convert them to text in excel first.

Comment: Seems to me that [Openpyxl support is coming to excel_read()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/25092) *soon-ish* (i.e. has a milestone for the next `pandas` version, 0.25.0); apart from this, I don't think much has changed since the 3-year-old (duplicate?) question you've found already.

Comment: @QuangHoang  df = df.astype(str) did nothing, well it converts the underlying data to str not the values we see in excel.