# Read csv can't read currency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I correctly read a CSV with currency symbols? I tried many encodings

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding="windows-1252")
```

```
df
     â‚¬ discount  â‚¬price
0      1            2
```

Expected Output:

```
df
     € discount  €price
0      1            2
```

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334400/not-able-to-read-currency-symbol-from-the-cell-using-pandas-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't sure of the encoding, do this:

```
with open("my_data.csv", 'rb') as rawdata:
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(10000))
```

This will return information about the file, including it encoding. Then:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', encoding="the encoding you found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following csv file

```
€ discount,€ price
1,2
```

using just `pandas.read_csv` works fine for me:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

| € discount | € price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |