# pandas - read Excel data as formatted

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to read Excel data as it appears in Excel, not the intrinsic/underlaying data.

Now that Pandas has the ability to use "openpyxl" as the engine, is it possible to achieve this?

This is what the data looks like in Excel, its been formatted:

[image]

This is how panda reads the data in, you can see the intrinsic values are returned not the formatted values.
[image]

Notes -

-I am not interested in using openpyxl on its own, I have to use pandas

-I have tried to read the data in as string but converts the underlaying data to string, it does not read data as it appears.

Similar to this question but it was asked almost 3 years ago. [pandas read excel as formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038428/pandas-read-excel-as-formatted)

Comment: I really don't think this is possible. Since the underlying data is well... underlying. Excel still has that value, regardless of format, under the hood. Excel is just displaying the format that you chose on top of that number. It does not change the underlying data.

Comment: Different formatting can be applied in many different ways; the underlying data will be exactly the same no matter what.  What's your end game?

Comment: I want to extract the data as it appears and then do some calculations. It will save me a lot of time. Instead of convert 0.45 to 45 myself for example. Just one example.