# How can I prevent the € symbol from getting cut out when converting xlsx to csv using Python 3.9 and Pandas?

Tags: excel, converters, python-3.9

I want to convert csv to xlsx and vice versa.
It works finde but the € symbol gets cutted out and 5€ gets converted to just 5.

```
        for file_path in self.input_files:
            file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)
            output_file = os.path.join(self.output_folder, os.path.basename(file_name))

            if file_ext.lower() == '.csv':
                output_file += '.xlsx'
                df = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', decimal=',', encoding='utf-8-sig')
                df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)
            elif file_ext.lower() == '.xlsx':
                output_file += '.csv'
                df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
                df.to_csv(output_file, index=False, sep=';', quotechar='"', decimal=',', float_format='%.15g', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

This is the loop where i convert these files. Any idea how to fix my Problem?

Tried different encodings, and in the manual of pandas i didnt find anything useful

Edit: When i only use €, it will correct be converted to €. But with decimals the € gets cutted out. With the dollar sign instead it works perfect.

Comment: Is the `€` applied with a number format in Excel?

Comment: No as a currency. As soon i put € in there, it switches to currency. In the converted csv its again the standard format

Comment: If i save the xlsx manually through excel, its still 5€ and the format is currency

Comment: That means that Excel is smart enough to convert the applied format to an actual value. I highly doubt this will work with pandas. Try using `openpyxl`.

Comment: Do you know ad hoc how to manipulate the code with openpyxl?

Comment: You might consider the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: [Perhaps useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038428/pandas-read-excel-as-formatted).