# reading format info for .xlsx files using xlrd

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, xlrd

I found an earlier thread on this indicating this functionality is not implemented in XLRD for .xlsx files

reference to the earlier thread - 
[python xlutils : formatting_info=True not yet implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892307/python-xlutils-formatting-info-true-not-yet-implemented)

checking back to see if there is any update on this being supported in latest versions of xlrd or if there are any alternative python packages that can help with this.

Comment: took a look at the latest xlrd code from github and seem like this feature is still not implemented  - https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/xlsx.py

Comment: looks like no plans to add this in xlrd - https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/223