# Getting the URL from Excel Sheet Hyper links in Python with xlrd

Tags: python, excel, hyperlink, xlrd

I am trying to get the hyperlinks URL of elements in the 2nd column of an Excel sheet using xlrd.
When using:

```
book = open_workbook('mypath', formatting_info=True)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
r_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
wb = copy(book)
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)

for row_index in range(1, sheet.nrows):    
    URL = sheet.hyperlink_map.get((row_index, 1))
    print URL
```

I get:

```
<xlrd.sheet.Hyperlink object at 0x0000000002D81898>
<xlrd.sheet.Hyperlink object at 0x0000000002D819E8>
<xlrd.sheet.Hyperlink object at 0x0000000002D81DA0>
```

What do I have to add to my code to get URL formatted in a string format and not an xlrd.sheet.Hyperlink object so they can be later used in the code? I am looking to get the actual URL that I see when highlighting the elements of the first column in Excel, so something like *http://www.mywebpage.com*

Comment: `if URL is not None: print URL.url_or_path`

Comment: Have you tried `URL = sheet.hyperlink_map.get((row_index, 1)).url_or_path`; I found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056892/getting-a-hyperlink-url-from-an-excel-document?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi,  the program will crash using your version

Comment: Zeinad, I get
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'url_or_path'`

Comment: @LaGuille, did you try what the code from my comment?

Comment: Nvm, It works using URL.url_or_path, my mistake!

Comment: according  to the docs it returns  *The URL or file-path, depending in the type. Unicode string, except in the rare case of a local but non-existent file with non-ASCII characters in the name, in which case only the "8.3" filename is available, as a bytes (3.x) or str (2.x) string, with unknown encoding*

Comment: I thought so, I was wondering how a xlrd.sheet.Hyperlink object  became a tuple ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, yes, you are right, I should also consider `None` value for `URL` as you said in comments; I supposed it won't occur.