# How to make XLRD read hyperlinks in XLSX cells?

Tags: python, excel, hyperlink, xlrd

This is not a duplicate although the issue has been raised in this forum in 2011[Getting a hyperlink URL from an Excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056892/getting-a-hyperlink-url-from-an-excel-document), 2013 [Extracting Hyperlinks From Excel (.xlsx) with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676727/extracting-hyperlinks-from-excel-xlsx-with-python) and 2014 [Getting the URL from Excel Sheet Hyper links in Python with xlrd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566983/getting-the-url-from-excel-sheet-hyper-links-in-python-with-xlrd); there is still no answer. 
After some deep dive into the xlrd module, it seems the Data_sheet.hyperlink_map.get((row, col)) item trips because "xlrd cannot read the hyperlink without formatting_info, which is currently not supported for xlsx" per @alecxe at [Extracting Hyperlinks From Excel (.xlsx) with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676727/extracting-hyperlinks-from-excel-xlsx-with-python).
Question: has anyone has made progress with extracting URLs from hyperlinks stored in an excel file. Say, of all the customer data, there is a column of hyperlinks. I was toying with the idea of dumping the excel sheet as an html page and proceed per usual scraping (file on local drive). But that's not a production solution. Supplementary: is there any other module that can  extract the url from a .cell(row,col).value() call on the hyperlink-cell. Is there a solution in mechanize? Many thanks.

Comment: Would love to know myself too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to get the hyperlinks from the cells of a xlsx file. The work around I came up with is simply converting the Excel sheet to xls format, from which I could manage to get the hyperlinks withount any trouble, and once finished the editing, I formatted it back to the original xlsx file.

I don't know if this should work for your specific needs, or if the change of format implies some consecuences I am not aware of, but I think it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to read and use hyperlinks to copy files with `openpyxl`. It has a `cell_obj.hyperlink` and `cell_obj.hyperlink.target` which will grab the link value. I made a list of the cell row col values which had hyperlinks, then appended them to a list and then looped through the list to move the linked files.